# Pasar el contenido de una tabla a otra con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

quería solicitar su ayuda con una consulta en Mysql que es para pasar todo el contenido de una tabla a otra dentro de la misma base de datos, pero no se como hacerla a través de de PDO PHP, esta es mi consulta:

```
INSERT INTO warehouses (war_mat_id, war_mst_id, war_ser_id, war_serie, war_guia, war_pro_id, war_identificador,war_nwa_id, war_use_id, created_at)
SELECT temp_mat_id, temp_mst_id, temp_ser_id, temp_serie,temp_guia,temp_pro_id,temp_identificador,temp_nwa_id,temp_use_id,temp_created_at
FROM temp
```

Si esta consulta la ejecuto directo en la consola de mysql, funciona sin problemas, pero mi problema es que no se como estructurarla con PDO, intente hacerla así, pero no me funciona.

```
   <?php
    $nombre_tabla='temp';
   $sql_insert_war ="INSERT INTO warehouses (war_mat_id, war_mst_id, war_ser_id, war_serie, war_guia, war_pro_id, war_identificador,war_nwa_id, war_use_id, created_at) 
    SELECT temp_mat_id, temp_mst_id, temp_ser_id, temp_serie,temp_guia,temp_pro_id,temp_identificador,temp_nwa_id,temp_use_id,temp_created_at FROM '.$nombre_tabla.'";
    $insertar_war =$pdo->prepare($sql_insert_war);
    $insertar_war->execute();
    ?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Tu último código da algún error?

Comment: Prueba a mirar si el propio PDO te está dando error de conexión, porque lo que es el  código SQL está correcto, aunque si estás usando todas las columnas podrías simplificarlo a `INSERT INTO warehouses SELECT * FROM tabla2 `

Comment: hola @BetaM, la verdad es que no se como ver si me muestra algún error, ya que el código esta en una pagina php que ejecuto desde javascript, pero las otras consultas a la BD que están en esa misma pagina si las ejecuta, pero esta no logro que la ejecute .

Comment: Busca en la doc de PHP el método `errorInfo` que es de PDO y te puede ayudar a comprobar si la consulta tiene algún error

Comment: @BetaM  y Benito-B  gracias por su ayuda, mi error estaba mi consulta, con el errorInfo pude darme cuenta cual era, el nombre de la tabla lo paso por una variable y yo lo estaba concatenando dentro de la consulta "FROM '.$nombre_tabla.' " y no era necesario puse la variable directo en la consulta y funciono lo deje así : "FROM $nombre_tabla"